# TortoiseSVN client closes connection after TLS 'server hello'

Tags: ssl, tortoisesvn

After updating the TortoiseSVN client to version 1.14.6 SSL connections to our internal SVN server (using a self signed certificate) get immediately closed after receiving the 'Server Hello' message.

[image]

Reverting the client version to 1.14.5 makes the server access work like expected.
Is there a way to further investigate what's the reason for the immediately closing of the connection.

Comment: What do you see in the output of TortoiseSVN? Any error messages? And what SVN server are you using? What is its version?

Comment: The error message shown after access is `E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication`
The svn version running on the server is old as dirt `svnadmin, Version 1.6.11 (r934486)`  

Therefore apache is also using an ancient SSL version. Is it possible that these old versions cause the access problem?

Comment: You need to upgrade your server so that it uses modern TLS versions. Most likely the problem occurs because the server doesn't speak TLS. Or downgrade TortoiseSVN to the version that works with your server.